# Первый экран на чистом css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать так, чтобы показывалась только та часть , которая помещается на экране? т.е. есть 1-й экран: верхнее меню и дальше див с большим изображением. Как его обрезать под высоту экрана?
без js

```
.first-monitor{         
    background-image: url("/img/first.png");
    background-position: center top;        
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;         
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: поставить overflow:hidden

Comment: первым это попробовал - не сработало

Comment: покажи как пробовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам просто нужно `body` на 100% растянуть

```css
/* reset */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.first-monitor{
  background-image: url("http://bemarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/HTML_153031724.jpg"); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-monitor"></div>
```

### UPD

Для затемнения картинки сверху можно например добавить `box-shadow`:

```
.first-monitor{
    // предыдущие стили
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 80px -80px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 80px -80px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 80px -80px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Удобный сервис для создания теней – http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Comment: @kotytoff а как добавить сверху на картинку затемнение с указанным числом?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron вы имеете ввиду `box-shadow`?

Comment: да, спасибо. box-shadow работает как надо

Comment: Момент один: после такого решения уже никаких блоков под картинкой не добавишь. Как это пофиксить? Чтобы только заданый див кадрировался под размер экрана.

Comment: Так вам только фон нужно под экран растянуть? Тогда нужно было вопрос по другому ставить

Comment: перечитал свой вопрос. Вы правы - я не корректно поставил вопрос.
Да, только в рамках одного div нужно растянуть фон

Comment: То есть вы хотите растянуть первый (условно первый) элемент на странице по высоте экрана? Для этого пока только `JS`, на `CSS` как то можно было уже не во всех браузерах это реализовать, но точно не помню

Comment: Пошел через calc(100% - 15vh)